# Where should I alter the contents of List<Object> after receiving it from network call?

Tags: android

After making a network call using retrofit, I get a list of objects. The object is just a class with getters and setters. However for one of the values of  the object, is date_posted which is retrieved as a long (unix time - 1575817038). I have a method Utils.CalculateTime(long date_posted) that returns a string after converting the timestamp to a string time (eg. December 7th, 7:00pm).

My question is where should I place this method to calculate the time?

**Right after the onSuccessful network call?**

```
RetrofitInterfaces.ICommentReply service = RetrofitClientInstance.getRetrofitInstance().create(RetrofitInterfaces.ICommentReply.class);
        Call<PostComments> call = service.listRepos(postComments);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<PostComments>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<PostComments> call, Response<PostComments> response) {

              for (PostComments comments : mPostComments) {
                    comments.setDate_posted(MethodCalculateTime.calculateAge(mServerTime, 
                    Long.valueOf(comments.getDate_posted())));
              }

}
```

**In my POJO's getters and setters?**

```
public String getDate_posted() {
    return date_posted;
}

public void setDate_posted(String date_posted) {
    String time = Utils.CalculateTime(date_posted);
    this.date_posted = time;
}
```

**In my Adapter's Constructor before I bind the views?**

```
public CommentsAdapter(List<PostComments> mList, Context mContext) {
        this.mList = mList;
        this.mContext = mContext;

        for (PostComments comments : mPostComments) {
                    comments.setDate_posted(MethodCalculateTime.calculateAge(mServerTime, 
                    Long.valueOf(comments.getDate_posted())));
              }

    }
```

**Or someother place?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you should use the same field `date_posted` to store either a long timestamp converted to a String or a formatted date, because then how will you know in your code what format is used? At some stage you'll have the raw timestamp and in others the formatted date.

The best would be to have two fields, one `timestamp_posted` that is a long, and one `formatted_date_posted` that is a string. In the long setter, convert the long to a formatted date, so you know the formatted date is always in sync.

```
public void setTimestamp_posted(long ts){
   this.timestamp_posted=ts;
   this.formatted_date_posted=Utils.CalculateTime(ts);
}

public String getFormatted_date_posted(){
   return this.formatted_date_posted;
}
```

Comment: In the setter for the timestamp. Added sample code to my answer.

Comment: Oh I see. But in my case settimestamp is never called because the network call returns a List <Comments>. So I would have to manually call settimestamp on each object in the list. So I was unsure where to place the loop to format the timestamp to string

Comment: The most important thing is to have two fields since you're storing 2 different things. Then you can calculate the formatted date when you want, when it's needed,etc.